# To break html table row to next line to convert to pdf

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, css-paged-media

I want to convert an HTML table into pdf to take a print. But while converting into pdf table row goes beyond the page so I want to ***break*** the table row to next line. Is there any HTML table attribute or CSS to make that happen?

Comment: what library for pdf conversion are you using? jsPDF, pdkMake? or what?

Comment: Im using python weasyprint library in django

Comment: so you are generating the pdf on the backend not the frontend?

Comment: Yes. at background

Answer (score 0):

If long text makes your rows too wide, maybe the CSS `word-wrap` Attribute can help you.

For example: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/

Comment: I don't think this will work for pdf files since you want to send on page break

Comment: I think you're right - he DID ask for CSS to manage his table though.

Comment: Yes he did ask for CSS maybe not knowing that it won't work on PDFs